# How design algorithm battle fight between players

Tags: algorithm

I need to create simple (or not simple for :D ) rules to my game. So my idea is all players has four parameters:

```
Energy user1 = 100
Power user1 = 100
Speed user1 = 5
Resistance user1 = 25

Energy user2 = 100
Power user2 = 110
Speed user2 = 10
Resistance user2 = 30
```

I need a fight system. This is my algorithm:

```
1. Random power range (20% - 80%)
2. Random resistance (20% - 80%)
3. power user1 = 100 * 30% (random example)
4. resistance user1 = 25 * 50% (random example)
5. power user2 = 110 * 30% = 33
6. resistance user2 = 30 * 50% = 15
7. power user1 = power user1 - resistance user 2: 30 - 15 = 15
8. power user2 = power user2 - resistance user 1: 33 - 12.5 = 20.5
9. if user1 speed > user2 speed power user1 = power user1 + (power user1 * 10%)
9. if user2 speed > user1 speed power user2 = power user2 + (power user2 * 10%)
for example user1 and user2 has the same speed
10. lucky user1 and user2 = random range (-3% to 3%) and (add or remove) to power user1 and user2
11. Winner is person who has more and power
```

The winner get XP like this:

```
1. lost point user1 = end power user1/user2 speed
2. lost point user2 = end power user2/user1 speed
3. ptg = abs(lost point user1 = lost point user2)
4. this ptg remove from loser power and add to winner XP
```

Collect XP and training user in 3 ways: power, speed, resistance

My point is when i simulation and set user1 to 200 points of power this user always win.
No matter how i split the same 100 XP between rest of ways on user 2.

For example

```
Energy user1 = 100
Power user1 = 200
Speed user1 = 5
Resistance user1 = 25

Energy user2 = 100
Power user2 = 140
Speed user2 = 45
Resistance user2 = 45
```

User1 always wins. So do you know some good algorithm to battle fight and how should i calculate to remove or add energy? I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different algorithms that I can suggest

**Accumulate Damage**

User1 always wins the first battle, but takes damage.  For example `power user1 = 200` and `power user2 = 140`.  After beating user2, user1 is left with `power user1 = 60`.  If user1 fights another battle before recovering, he has a much lower power, and will probably lose.

**Random Damage**

In this algorithm, the damage to user2 is equal to a random percentage of user1's power, and vice versa.  So if `power user1 = 200` and `power user2 = 140`, then damage to user2 is a random number between 0 and 200, and damage to user1 is a random number between 0 and 140. Keep accumulating random damage until one player is defeated.  In this algorithm, user1 is not guaranteed to win, but does have an advantage if both players are equally lucky.

Comment: In Accumulate if User1 attac User2 then User1 will be dead. In Random Damage if user1 attac user2 and user1 random power 190, then user1 will be dead. Am I right ?

Comment: I think user2 is dead in both cases, but otherwise yes, that's the general idea.

Comment: And what about speed and resistance? Can i make some algorithm to manipulate this random values? so if user1 attac user2 and user1 rand for example 90 power to hit opponent. So user2 can make remove some power calculating with speed and resistance for example user1 will not hit with 90 but only 70 ???

Comment: Speed is usually used to determine who hits first. So if user1 has higher speed, then user1 hits first, and then the players alternate. For resistance, subtract the resistance from the opponent's power but keep above some minimum amount, e.g. `user1 effective power = user1 power - user2 resistance` but `if effective power < 10 then effective power = 10`.

Comment: Perfect idea for me i think. This will be fight beetween two users. Speed set who is first. Resistance substance effective power. And power is a range of damage. User not must dead in first fight. So i will calculate after fight their damages. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Spreadsheets are used for this type of number crunching to test gaming algorithms.
It makes testing an assorted number of inputs against the same functions very easy